# Color conversion

Tags: objective-c, colors

I was looking around without any luck how to convert some color code into plain RGB (255,255,255). I have this kind of number like

```
5953244  Yellow
12868826 Pink
12356730 Pale Blue
5758835  Green
```

I truly don't understand how to take this numbers and process them into regular RGB or what kind of RGB type are.

Comment: I wish to accept every answer because they are valid but I can only one :(

Comment: refer this link to convert hexcode to UIcolor: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An int is large enough to hold an ARGB value or any order (RGBA, BGR) and the int value itself is not as important as the individual bytes it contains. Different color spaces requires different bitwise operations since the channel will be located at different bytes. The following is an example that would work for `RGB` and `ARGB`.

```
#define R(rgb) ((rgb) >> 16 & 0xFF)
#define G(rgb) ((rgb) >> 8 & 0xFF)
#define B(rgb) ((rgb) & 0xFF)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pale_blue = 5953244;
    printf("\nR: 0x%02X G: 0x%02X B: 0x%02X\nR: %03d G: %03d B: %03d", 
        R(pale_blue), G(pale_blue), B(pale_blue), 
        R(pale_blue), G(pale_blue), B(pale_blue));
}
```

Output:

> R: 0x5A  G: 0xD6  B: 0xDC 
>   R: 090     G: 214     B: 220

Comment: I can't resist to say: very nice!

Comment: @nathan-day it's wierd, it works for Green and Pink (not really pink,but very close) but the other two are wrong. Pale Bluebecome brown and Yellow a pure cyan. I truly have no idea of what kind of int color system are, that's the main problem. This comes from a XML on Windows. I have no other clues :(

Answer (score 2):

Simply include this line in your header file:

```
#define RGB(r, g, b)  [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Then you can call it from anywhere like this:

```
UIColor *myBrightBlueColour = RGB(0,186,255);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of colour codes these are, if they are html colour codes that are normally shown as hex then you can do something like this

```
red = (c>>16)&0xff;
green = (c>>8)&0xff;
blue = c&0xff;
```

Comment: more than I expected, tnx! :)